# Padding error after partial reading final block

Tags: c#, cryptography, rijndael

I am trying to test my cryptography code and keep getting the CyrptographicException "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed" when ever `decrypt` is disposed.  I get a similar error if I try to read past the end of the `decrypt` stream, even though the [`CryptoStream.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.read.aspx) documentation indicates that this should not be an issue.

A simplified example:

```
const int DATA_SET_SIZES = 102399;

byte[] iv,
        key,
        startingData = new byte[DATA_SET_SIZES],
        encryptedData = new byte[((DATA_SET_SIZES - 1) / 16 + 2) * 16],
        endingData = new byte[DATA_SET_SIZES];//[((DATA_SET_SIZES - 1) / 16 + 1) * 16];
Random rand = new Random();

rand.NextBytes(startingData);       //Get test data.

using (Rijndael cryptAlg = Rijndael.Create())
{
    cryptAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    cryptAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.ISO10126;

    iv = cryptAlg.IV;               //Use random IV during test.
    key = cryptAlg.Key;             //Use random Key during test.
    using (CryptoStream encrypt = new CryptoStream(new MemoryStream(encryptedData), cryptAlg.CreateEncryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
        encrypt.Write(startingData, 0, startingData.Length);
        encrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
    }
    using (CryptoStream decrypt = new CryptoStream(new MemoryStream(encryptedData), cryptAlg.CreateDecryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
    {
        int dataRecieved = decrypt.Read(endingData, 0, endingData.Length);
    }
}
```

If I do one of the following then the exception goes away:

- Change `cryptAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.None` after performing the encryption but before creating `decrypt`.
- Change `const int DATA_SET_SIZES = 102400` or any other multiple of the block size.
- Do not read any data from the last block.

Am I doing something wrong or does the .NET implementation not recognize the end of the stream correctly?

Also, does anyone know why the encrypted data is 1 block longer then would be needed to store the encrypted data?  What is in that block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `encryptedData` buffer is too large. Take input 15 bytes, then you get 32 blocks of buffer back. Since you give the full buffer to the `MemoryStream` constructor, it will read up to the end of the stream. Block decryption will *never* fail, so the only thing that will fail is the padding. The last block probably only contains zero's, so the decrypted value is random instead of matching the padding format (most of the time).

Try: `new byte[(DATA_SET_SIZES / 16 +`**`1`**`) * 16]`

Comment: I had tried that before with `DATA_SET_SIZES = 102400` and got a `NotSupportedException` "Memory stream is not expandable.".  I just tried it again with `DATA_SET_SIZES = 102399` and `DATA_SET_SIZES = 102401` and it worked fine.  I guess there needs to be an extra byte in the buffer for `PaddingMode.ISO10126` to indicate that the end has been reached.  I have updated (removed the -1) and accepted your answer.  Thanks, I spent hours on that.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, forgot to remove the -1 as well. ISO 10126 (just like the almost identical PKCS#7 padding) *always* pads, so it add a full block when you have 16 bytes of plain text data.